# OS X - Use mach read/write functions without requiring root/sudo

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

So I know it's possible to use vm_read_overwrite and vm_write without asking the user to type in their password every single time your app launches.

I have an app that does this. I know you need to sign your application, then a password dialog will be displayed if your app reads/writes another process. You generally type in the root password once and then the app runs as your local user.

My problem is I'm creating a new app, which I signed, but it's not posting the dialog for permission.

Am I missing another step here? Worst case I can copy/paste my existing project, but I'd rather not as it's quite large.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it, needed SecTaskAccess set to allowed in Info.plist

http://os-tres.net/blog/2010/02/17/mac-os-x-and-task-for-pid-mach-call/